# How to move a DOM element into a separate component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-portal

I am trying to move a DOM element in one component into a separate component. Basically, the `div` needs to move up two parent levels.

[image: Current placement of the DOM element]

[image: Goal placement of the DOM element]

I have two components at play:

1. AuthFlow.js
2. SignUp.js

```js
//AuthFlow.js
{renderForm()}
      {formType === 'signUp' && (
        // This div needs to move up 
        <div className="mt-6">
          <p className="font-body text-white">
            Already have an account?{' '}
            <span
              className="text-quad cursor-pointer"
              onClick={() => updateFormType('signIn')}
            >
              Sign In
            </span>
          </p>
        </div>
      )}
```

```js
// SignUp.js
... 
</div>
        <button
          className="transition-all transform hover:translate-y-1 rounded-md bg-tertiary py-3 mt-6 cursor-pointer border-2 border-transparent focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-tertiary focus:border-transparent"
          onClick={signIn}
          title="Sign In"
        >
          Sign in
        </button>
        // Eventual placement of the Div I want to move
      </form>
```

I've looked into React portals, but I am not sure if that is the way to go.

Comment: At what point are you trying to move it up ? Is it based on a state change ? Then you can simply manage a state inside your parent and pass it down to the relevant child component. Then you can have your moving component in parent and also in child. Then using that state you can disable it in child and show it in parent and do the other way round as well.

Comment: You can solve this using portals but I don't think using portals is a good idea because it will make your code cumbersome to debug.

Why not mount AuthFlow.js inside SignUp.js ?